# $.event.special.swipe.horizontalDistanceThreshold returns its default value only(30px) in every swipe

Tags: jquery-mobile, swipe, image-gallery

I am trying to find the horizontal distance of swipe in jquery mobile. In every swap it returns its default value(30) only.
I had tried by following way:

```
 $('.ad-thumb-list').on("swipeleft swiperight",function(event){
   //alert("swipe");
        if(event.type == 'swipeleft'){
        // alert("left");

            alert($.event.special.swipe.horizontalDistanceThreshold); //i expect the different threshold values in different swipe..
            galleries[0].nextImage();
        }
        else if(event.type == 'swiperight'){
            //alert("right");
            galleries[0].prevImage();
        }
});
```

P.S I am using AD gallery plugin.

Comment: The 30px is the minimum horizontal distance a user should pass in order to trigger swipe event, so it's always fixed. Use touch events to calculate distance.

Comment: sir will you please elaborate it?  I tried tap, taphold. Still i am not getting the result.

Comment: Im not sure there is an inbuilt in way for JQM to display how many pixels you swiped, You may need an alternative --- http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/Swipe_status.html

Comment: @Tasos i have already tried this plugin. I face some click incompatibility problems, and i move back to jquery mobile swipe event. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: Youre right, i just tested this --- http://blog.blakesimpson.co.uk/read/51-swipe-js-detect-touch-direction-and-distance ---- and it doesnt work also.  Ill have a look and see if can find a JQM method

Comment: This person here found a solution --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416033/how-to-get-direction-and-distance-with-jquery-mobiles-swipe-event  -- Yep it works. Just delete the // in the demo to show the pixels

Comment: @Tasos thank you for suggesting this. It seems like it is working now.

Comment: Yeah (Gajotres) seems to know his stuff, I was just checking his website, its got a lot of interesting info on JQM.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually get the swipe distance (and time) by setting up your own handleSwipe function, where you get start and stop objects.   After you've done whatever you need with them, you will decide to trigger a swipe or not.   This just hooks into the [default handler code found here](http://api.jquerymobile.com/swipe/).

```
    $.event.special.swipe.handleSwipe = function( start, stop ) {
        $("#about-delta-x").html("delta-x: " + (stop.coords[0]-start.coords[0]).toString());
        if ( stop.time - start.time < $.event.special.swipe.durationThreshold &&
            Math.abs( start.coords[ 0 ] - stop.coords[ 0 ] ) > $.event.special.swipe.horizontalDistanceThreshold &&
            Math.abs( start.coords[ 1 ] - stop.coords[ 1 ] ) < $.event.special.swipe.verticalDistanceThreshold ) {
            start.origin.trigger( "swipe" )
                .trigger( start.coords[0] > stop.coords[ 0 ] ? "swipeleft" : "swiperight" );
        }
    };
```